# Can the French embassy cancel my US visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, b1-b2-visas, long-stay-visas

I'm applying for a French student visa soon in India and since I'm unemployed at this point in time,I wanted to continue my education in France so I can get better opportunities here when I come back. I do however have a B1/B2 visa valid for ten years issued outside of my home country.

Although I haven't used it in a long time and neither do I plan to use it again soon, I would like to know if the French embassy can cancel my US visitor visa or pass my information to the US embassy for visa cancellation in case I don't qualify for the French student visa itself. I know that when you're unemployed, you don't qualify for a B2 visa until you're employed back again. Am I overthinking it ? I would appreciate anyone's advise on this.

Comment: Hi Pnuts,
Thanks for replying back!  Actually one of the reason why I'm planning to study in France is because I feel that a French degree can help me improve my profile. And I haven't actually heard if being unemployed disqualifies you for a B1/B2 visa but that being said you do need to show strong ties for a US visitor/business visa and unless you're retired, without a job, it's almost impossible to get it. So I wanted to know if I disqualify for a French student visa, would that also mean that my US visa be in jeopardy as well.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not think that you have any reason to worry.

Remember that each country sets its own criteria for visa issuance, and that the criteria are different for different *types* of visas.

France is not part of the United States, and will not be concerned with whether you qualify for the B1/B2 visa. It will be sufficient for them that you have it.

Because visitor visas have different requirements than student visas, it's unlikely that anyone at the French consulate could even guess whether you continue to qualify for the US *visitor* visa, given that your application to them should be designed to show you meet the requirements for a *student* visa.

There is one thing though. If, while processing your visa application, France determines that you are wanted in the US for a crime, they might notify the US of your location. (And most likely refuse your visa.)

Comment: @pnuts I can't yet see any plausible scenario in which the US _would_ find out.

Comment: Michael Hampton- Thanks for answering my question! No! I have a very clean record, so there shouldn't be any concerns regarding that.

Comment: Pnuts- Thanks for another feedback. I guess for people in the "third world"  getting visas for any country can be a nerve-wrecking task.